# Optimization - matching sequence of words in dataframe column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a list of sequences of words and I'm trying to determine whether a string column contains any of the sequences in the list. If there is any match, the new column should contain 1, otherwise it should be 0.
The below code achieves that, however it does not scale well for large data.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re

data = {'TextVar' : ['this should never match',
'matches foo bar',
'this is the second random pattern',
np.nan,
'foo bars, should return 0',
'foo bar, with a comma, should return 1']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
patterns = ['foo bar', 'second random pattern', 'pink unicorns',]

def stringFound(string1, string2):
    """
    string1 = pattern to look for
    string2 = string to look in
    """
    if pd.isnull(string1) or pd.isnull(string2):
        return False
    if re.search(r"\b" + re.escape(string1) + r"\b", string2):
        return True
    return False

def hasPattern(pattern_list, text):
    for e in pattern_list:
       if stringFound(e, text):
           return 1        
    return 0

df['Output'] = df.apply(lambda x :hasPattern(patterns, x['TextVar']), axis=1)
```

I tried running this on a list of 5000 sequences ( `len(patterns) = 5000`) and with 15000 rows in the dataframe and after 30 minutes it is still running. I realize that I'm actually iterating a potential 75 million times - how could I write this in order to be more time efficient?

Comment: Perhaps, you just want to use `df['TextVar'].str.contains(r'\b{}\b'.format('|'.join(patterns)))`. I see no need to use `re.escape` if you use `\b`. You might want to use `r'(?<!\w){}(?!\w)'.format('|'.join([re.escape(m) for m in patterns]))` in case your patterns may contain non-word chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [16]: pat = '|'.join([r'\b{}\b'.format(x) for x in patterns])

In [17]: pat
Out[17]: '\\bfoo bar\\b|\\bsecond random pattern\\b|\\bpink unicorns\\b'

In [18]: df['TextVar'].fillna('').str.contains(pat).astype(np.int8)
Out[18]:
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    0
4    0
5    1
Name: TextVar, dtype: int8
```

PS in case of using more complex patterns, try to use a pattern from [@Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46546005/optimization-matching-sequence-of-words-in-dataframe-column#comment80046186_46546005):

```
pat = r'(?<!\w){}(?!\w)'.format('|'.join([re.escape(m) for m in patterns]))
```

Comment: There is a gotcha here: if `patterns` contain a value like `Dr.`, the `\bDr\.\b` will never match in `Dr. Smith`. I am not sure that part is clear in the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thank you! Do you think using `re.escape()` is a preferred way in this case?

Comment: Well, it is always a good idea, but we do not know the real data OP has. I do not want to be too pro-active here, but `r"\b" + re.escape(string1) + r"\b"` does not look safe since `\b` are context dependent. I'd rahter use `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)` instead to avoid the issues like I mentioned above.

Comment: The real data in `patterns` will never contain any punctuation, so there's no need to be pro-active. Just tested this and it run in 73 seconds on my laptop - great job!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thank you! I've added you RegEx to the answer - it might help those who has more complicated patterns...